# Exiftool shortens string output

Tags: exiftool

I am trying to get a string output using Exiftool. The original value should be:

```
  1.00000095367432 -0.00040300001273863 -0.000503999995999038 0.000391999987186864 0.9999960064888 0.00425100000575185 -0.00258799991570413 -0.00425100000575185 0.999997973442078
```

But when I run the command:

```
exiftool -a -u -TAG image.jpg
```

Exiftool shortens the output. It returns:

```
1.00000095367432 -0.00040300001273863 -0.00050399999599[...]
```

How can I get the entire string value?

Comment: What tag are you trying to read?  What version of exiftool are you using?  Is `[...]` the actual output returned?  I have been unable to replicate your example.

Comment: The tag is using is from makernotes.  The version is the latest (10.61). Another thing.. that's a string (Unicode). Yes.. it returned [...] instead of the full output. Thanks!

Comment: What Is the exact tag are you trying to read?

Comment: -Manufacturer0x7121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the full output, try disabling [printConv](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#n---printConv).  You can do this for all tags with the `-n` option but if you are extracting other tags at the same time, you can use the per tag option by adding `#` to the end of the tag name e.g `exiftool -u -a -Manufacturer0x7121#` .